# How to consume OAuth 1.0 webservice in salesforce

Tags: apex, integration, webservices, rest, oauth

I have another application which I need to call and they are using OAuth 1.0.
now I am calling their system endpoint, I have client id and client secret only.

Do I need to generate token also?

because when I tested on Postman its working fine with just giving endpoint url, client id and client secret.

Can anyone help me with samples?

I am getting bad request 400 as a response...

Code:

```
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

        try {
            Http h = new Http();
            String authorizationHeader = '&client_Id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret;               

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(endpointurl);               
            req.setMethod('GET');                              
            req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);                
            req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            req.setHeader('Accept','application/json'); 
            res = h.send(req);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    return res;
```

Comment: did you add the end point in remote site setting in your salesforce org?

Comment: Yes. already added

Comment: @sagar if we have only client id and client secret then how we write rest webservice?

Comment: can you show the code what you have tried?

Comment: @sagar updated question with code i am trying